# Convert non Ascii hyphen to ascii cpp

Tags: c++, linux, ascii, non-ascii-characters

Convert non Ascii hyphen (-) which is bighypen to ascii, when I pasted big hyphen in VI editor it is pasting like this `(▒~@~S)`.

I have a requirement to identify this and replace with ASCII hyphen.

Comment: How is it encoded? Utf-8?

Comment: Instead of trying to convert anything, use the correct string type or set the environment's LC_ALL to use `whatever.utf8`. You aren't using the 7-bit US-ASCII anyway. Nobody does. Even in the US they use Latin1/ISO 8859-1.

Comment: Once you fix your environment, vi and all editors will start working with UTF8 too

Comment: When you say "VI editor", are you using **Vim** editor?  If so, what is your `:set fencs?` setting?  Is it something like `fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1`?

Comment: yes, it is fileencodings=ucs-bom